# Set notation for matrices where the elements have a given range of possible values

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a matrix where each element can only contain a value in $[-1,1]$. I introduce this matrix as follows:

$$\mathbf{A} \in [-1,1]^{m\times n}$$

Is this an acceptable way of doing that, or is there some standard way of doing this I'm not aware of?

Comment: As long as you define what you mean and it is not cumbersome then you can do whatever you like I guess. I do not know of any official notation for what you need either.

Comment: $A_{ij} \in [-1,1]$ for all $i,j$ such that $1 \leq i \leq m$, $1 \leq j \leq n$